# NPM auto-install gulp components

Tags: npm, gulp

I'm setting up gulp to do tasks to my JS files in a legacy .NET WebForms project.  I have installed NPM, which I then used to install Gulp, and I can successfully run gulp which executes my gulpfile.js.  Now I have dependencies to install using npm, like gulp-concat, gulp-uglify, etc.  I don't want every developer who opens the solution to have to type "npm install xlibrary" for every dependency.  Is there a way to have npm install a list of dependencies, perhaps through a config file (I think VS 2015 does it this way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create package.json file containing

```
{
  "name": "my-web-app",
  "description": "Hello world app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.4.1",
    "del": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-add-src": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-csso": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-main-bower-files": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-ruby-sass": "^1.0.5",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.2",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.7.8",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

In that file you write out all the dependancies, so then developer just types "npm install" and npm gets all needed packages.